# delete records 2 days older than latest record for each ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table with ca 200 different ID's. Each ID has data logged about 100-fold at different timestamps. I want to delete, for each ID separately the records 2 days older than the youngest record of that particular ID.
Aka, I want for each ID a list of at least 2 days. Some may be up to CURRENTDATE, other lists may be 2 days, starting last month.

Would this work?:

```
> DELETE FROM loggingTable WHERE (DATE_SUB( MAX(T_log),INTERVAL 48 HOUR)> T_log) GROUP BY ID
```

I don't want to delete my data....

Comment: _“I don't want to delete my data....”_ - then create a _copy_, and test on that …

Comment: @CBroe. I meant :  I don't want to delete to much data and assume I did what I expected.

Comment: then create careful test conditions where you can verify it. If it's wrong, restore the data in your test environment back again to the previous state (which you created a backup of), and try again. This called unit-testing your code, and is part of the nuts and bolts of coding. Yes if you're experienced you may be able to be certain beforehand that a particular piece of code will work just by looking at it, but usually this skill comes through lots of testing and trial and error. And since we can't see your data, it's hard to know if your query will work on it, anyway

Comment: Ok, it doesn't work, I wouldn't aks if it did. What did I miss ?

Comment: we don't know for sure because we can't see your source data, and you haven't said precisely what went wrong. We need some sample data and expected output. Also the output you actually got from the current version of the code would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want to delete your data accidently, approach this problem in the following ways (from worst to best):

1. Create a copy of your data and work on that.
2. Do your operation in a transaction. This would work like

   ```
   START TRANSACTION;
   DELETE ...;
   SELECT ...; /* check if everything worked as expected*/
   /*if yes...*/
   COMMIT; /* this writes your changes on disk */
   /*if not, don't do a commit, but instead...*/
   ROLLBACK; /* this undoes all the statements in the transaction */
   ```
3. Write your `DELETE` statement as a `SELECT` statement first. Then check what would be deleted. If that is okay, transform it to a `DELETE` statement (and combine this approach with point 2 from above, if you like). For example like the following:

   ```
   SELECT 
   *
   FROM loggingTable lt
   JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(T_log)AS max_log FROM loggingTable GROUP BY ID) AS m ON lt.ID = m.ID
   WHERE lt.T_log < m.max_log - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
   ```

   If that looks okay:

   ```
   DELETE lt.*
   FROM loggingTable lt
   JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(T_log)AS max_log FROM loggingTable GROUP BY ID) AS m ON lt.ID = m.ID
   WHERE lt.T_log < m.max_log - INTERVAL 2 DAY;
   ```

Of course you can combine approaches 2 and 3 with 1 as well ;-)

Some additional explanation: The reason why I joined the query to the table is, that you can't use aggregate functions (like `MAX()`) in the `WHERE` clause. A sql statement is evaluated like this:

1. FROM
2. WHERE
3. GROUP BY
4. HAVING
5. ORDER BY
6. SELECT

Because the `where` clause is evaluated before the `group by` clause, you can't access the aggregate functions there. They are introduced with the `group by` clause.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.lt.T_log point back to original table whereas m.max_log points to the JOIN. grouped by ID. That's what I was looking for.